# Regarding JavaScript RegEx - Replace all punctuation including underscore

Tags: javascript, regex

In javascript, how can I replace all punctuation (including underscore) marks with hyphen? Moreover, it should not contain more than one hyphen sequentially.

I tried `"h....e   l___l^^0".replace(/[^\w]/g, "-")` but it gives me `h----e---l___l--0`

What should I do so that it returns me `h-e-l-l-0` instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`+` repeats the previous token one or more times.

```
> "h....e l___l^^0".replace(/[\W_]+/g, "-")
'h-e-l-l-0'
```

`[\W_]+` matches non-word characters or `_` one or more times.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to add an quatifier `+` to regex

```
"h....e   l___l^^0".replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/g, "-")
```

**NOTE**

- instead of `[^\w]` give `[^a-zA-Z0-9]+` because `\w` contains `_` hence it wont be replaced if you give `[^\w]`

Comment: I used `[\W_]` and it works as suggested by @Avinash Raj, thanks for help anyways!

Answer (score 1):

### [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/vI1hI5/1)

```
[!"#$%&'()*+,\-.\/:;<=>?@[\\\]^_`{|}~ ]+
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**Description**

```
[!"#$%&'()*+,\-.\/:;<=>?@[\\\]^_`{|}~ ]+ match a single character present in the list below
    Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
    !"#$%&'()*+, a single character in the list !"#$%&'()*+, literally (case sensitive)
    \- matches the character - literally
    . the literal character .
    \/ matches the character / literally
    :;<=>?@[ a single character in the list :;<=>?@[ literally (case sensitive)
    \\ matches the character \ literally
    \] matches the character ] literally
    ^_`{|}~  a single character in the list ^_`{|}~  literally
g modifier: global. All matches (don't return on first match)
```

**JS**

```
alert("h....e l___l^^0".replace(/[!"#$%&'()*+,\-.\/ :;<=>?@[\\\]^_`{|}~]+/g, "-"));
```

**Result:**

> h-e-l-l-0

Comment: Thanks for help, upvoted it; but @Avinash Raj's solution seems me the easiest!

Comment: @RuchirGupta not a problem hope it helps you in the future.